# Signature with canvas in html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#require-drawn for signature. In the demo it is working well. But when I used it in the web. Its clear functionality is not working.

```
<td >
    <span class="sigPad">
        <ul class="sigNav">

            <li ><a href="#draw-it" >Draw It</a></li>
            <li class="clearButton" ><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="sig sigWrapper">
            <div class="typed"></div>
            <canvas class="pad" width="198" height="55"></canvas>
            <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
            </div>

        </span>     
        <script src="js/signature/jquery.signaturepad.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('.sigPad').signaturePad({drawOnly:true});

            });
        </script>
        <script src="assets/json2.min.js"></script>


    </td>
```

Comment: Compare your code to the one on the website. Maybe you can figure out what is wrong. Did you load jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I added jQuery signature is working, but when I click "Clear" nothing is happening. I have checked with the website. But not getting anything. Do you have any idea to clear the content of the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Maybe you have a style that is conflicting with the "clearButton" class? I stated using his code for a project but wound up just writing my own.

```
<li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
```